# Initiate multiple named views from template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `ui-router` and have created a parent state with multiple child states like so:

```
.state('portfolio.patent', {
    url: '/:patentId',
    controller: 'patentItemCtrl',
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/patent/patent.patent-item.tpl.htm',

})
.state('portfolio.patent.patent-info', {
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/patent/patent.patent-info.tpl.htm',
    url: '/',
    controller: 'patentInfoCtrl',
    controllerAs: '$ctrl'      
})
.state('portfolio.patent.notifications', {
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/notifications/notifications.tpl.htm',
    url: '/',            
    controller: 'notificationsCtrl',
    controllerAs: '$ctrl'
})
```

I want these child states to load in seperate tabs, splits between a left and right `tabset` like so:

```
<div class="col-xl-6 ">
    <uib-tabset active="activeLeft">
        <uib-tab index="0" heading="Details" data-ui-sref=".patent-info"></uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
    <div ui-view></div> 
</div>
<div class="col-xl-6">
    <uib-tabset active="activeRight">
        <uib-tab index="1" heading="Notifications" data-ui-sref=".notifications"></uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

It semi-works in the sense that the views loads content, but of course without named views, the selected tab loads content in both the left and right `ui-view`, instead of `patent-info` loading in the left tabset, and `notifications` loading in the right tabset.

**Question**

If I adjust the ui-views to `<div ui-view="leftTab>` and `<div ui-view="rightTab">` what syntax do I use for `ui-sref` to do so?

For example: `data-ui-sref="@righTab.notifications"` (I know that isn't correct)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't structured your states properly for child views. Instead of having multiple states you need a single parent state that has a `views` property for its children. Here is a super contrived and simple example just to illustrate the use of child views. You can define a controller for each child view (in fact, I'm pretty sure it has all the same properties as a `state` except no `url`) just like you would for a regular state. Navigation occurs at the parent level so you never actually navigate to the child views, they are loaded with their parent.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
      .state('parent', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
          'leftTab': {
            template: '<div>This is the left tab</div>'
          },
          'rightTab': {
            template: '<div>This is the right tab</div>'
          }
        }
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.22/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ui-view>
    <div style="width: 40%; float: left; border: 1px solid black; margin-right: 5px;">
      <div ui-view="leftTab"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 40%; float: left; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: 5px;">
      <div ui-view="rightTab"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand that part but, with in the `leftTab` and `rightTab` view, I need the further views of `patent-info` and `notifications`. So essentially there would be the `parent` > then the child views     `leftTab` + `rightTab` (siblings) > then grandchild views`patent-info` (for leftTab) and `notifications` (for rightTab)

Comment: Hmm, that's a different structure than you indicated in your original question. In the case of the example I gave, `parent` would be `portfolio.patent`, `leftTab` would be `portfolio.patent.patent-info` and `rightTab` would be `portfolio.patent.notifications`. So you have a parent `portfolio` state and the template contains a `ui-view` which your `portfolio.patent` state is loaded into which contains the views for your left and right tabset.